# On click add 2 more form fields caching data? .net c#

Tags: c#, .net

Im working on a website where X amount of fields are show, I have a button beneath that allows the user to click and duplicate the same fields - I have this working, the only problem is that my data is caching, so when you click the button, all fields contained cloned values. Can anybody see where i may be going wrong?

```
private void NewDelegates()
{
    int NewDelegate = 2;
    if (ViewState["NewDelegate"] != null)
        NewDelegate = int.Parse(ViewState["NewDelegate"].ToString());
    else
        ViewState.Add("NewDelegate", 2);

    List<DelegateNoList> DelNo = new List<DelegateNoList>();
    for (int i = 0; i < NewDelegate; i++)
        DelNo.Add(new DelegateNoList { id = i });

    LV_Delegates.DataSource = DelNo;
    LV_Delegates.DataBind();
}

public class DelegateNoList
{
    public int id { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Retagged to `C#` and `.NET`

Answer (score 0):

Because you loop two times

your max is 2

```
int NewDelegate = 2;
```

initialized state is 0

```
for (int i = 0; i < NewDelegate; i++)
        DelNo.Add(new DelegateNoList { id = i });
```